# How to properly convert signInWithEmailAndPassword() to createCustomToken() in firebase cloud functions - Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I want to extend the default expiry time for the user token in my app. Currently i use signInWithEmailAndPassword function where the token lasts for an hour.

I know this can the done using the createcustomtoken function but I am a bit confused as to how to go about this.

This is my current login function:

```
exports.login = (req, res) => {
    const user = {
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    };

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
    .then((data) => {
        return data.user.getIdToken();
    })
    .then((token) => {
        return res.json({ token });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
            return res.status(403).json({ general: "Wrong credentials, please try again"})
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to extend the expiry time more than 3600 seconds past the issue at time (iat).

In this doc you can see the `exp` explicitly says:

> It can be a maximum of 3600 seconds later than the iat.

[custom token doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens)

You can however use the refresh token that doesn't have an expire time to get a new token.

[Refresh token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth)

If you wanted to still create your custom token, you could do something similar to:

```
const someJwt = jwtDecode<{ sub: string; email: string }>(someOtherTokenFromThirdParty)

// sub is the unique id for the apple user
const customToken = await admin.auth().createCustomToken(someJwt.sub, {
    ...extraClaims
})
```

Comment: thanks, this is helpful. I would use client sdk together with the admin sdk to get my desired result.